# Ignore sub sup elements in search

Tags: xquery, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

In continuation from the link-
([Ignore elements in cts:search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536381/ignore-elements-in-ctssearch/33537636#33537636ye))

I have for eg 3 scenarios for phrase search-

```
1. CO<sub>2</sub> lasers
2. <sup>2</sup>H- and <sup>3</sup>H-induced few nucleon transfer reactions
3. Mixed state, H<sub>c2</sub>, surface sheath
```

I have created a field query & defined it in a constraint named 'CL'.
Now-

1. CL:"CO2 lasers"

- Works with tokenizer overrides value set to 2, symbol.

2. CL:"2H- and 3H-induced few nucleon transfer reactions"

- Works with tokenizer overrides value set to 3, symbol. Does each additional occurrence of sub sup element increase the tokenizer character value?

3. CL:"Mixed state, Hc2, surface sheath"

- Fails for this scenario as it seems it works only for numerical values in sub,sup. In this case the value of sub is 'c2'. Is there a way we can make this work?

Also is there a solution to make this work in case of free text search?
for eg phrase search without using constants-
"CO2 lasers"
"2H- and 3H-induced few nucleon transfer reactions"
"Mixed state, Hc2, surface sheath"

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is an envelope pattern an option, or are you restricted to only indexing the data as-is? You could flatten out the value and persist a string in a separate element that is indexed, or maybe look to create a TDE and combine the view with other document search criteria if you have to index "as-is"?